# can create local search on google maps v3 

Tags: javascript, search, google-maps-api-3

i can't find  how to create it,

i can create it on google maps v2, use :

```
map.addControl(new google.maps.LocalSearch()
```

but now my company use v3 now ,

so  how to create it .

thanks

---

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r136/trunk/localsearch/places.html

Answer (score -1):

There's plenty of [great documentation on Google's Maps site](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). You'd probably be looking for the tutorial, though, which can be found here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/introduction.html

Hope this helps!